# Error when INSERTing into MySql via C++ Connector

Tags: c++, mysql

As stated in the title, I can connect to my DB, but I get an error when I try to insert into the table. Tried fixing it for 2 days, but cant figure out whats wrong about the syntax. The table exists with 2 columns of VARCHAR(20).

Heres my Code and the Error printed in the console:

```
#include "MainClass.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "User.h"

#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>


using namespace sql;

sql::Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con;
sql::Statement *stmt;
sql::ResultSet *res;

sf::TcpSocket socket;

bool running;

void login(std::string, std::string, std::string);
void Register(std::string, std::string, std::string);
void logout(std::string);

int main(void) {

    //DB Connection
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "******");
    stmt = con->createStatement();

    stmt->execute("USE login");

    Register("roflcat", "badumz", "192.168.0.2");
    login("roflcat", "badumz", "192.168.0.2");

    return0;
}

void Register(std::string name, std::string pw, std::string ip) {

    //HERE THE ERROR OCCURS:
    stmt->execute(("INSERT INTO user(name,pass) VALUES(%s,%s)", name, pw));

}
```

Error in Console:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'roflcat' at line 1created user roflcat

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Change the execute line into a print to the console.  Copy the line into MySql console application and see the error. Then fix the code.

Comment: wow, it actually just prints roflcat, guess i got something seriously wrong about how strings work in c++. Thanks so far!

Comment: You could also use a `PreparedStatement`.  See example here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-2.html

Comment: For some reason cout<< returns just "roflcat", while printf() returns the correct syntax, that doesnt return an error in mysql comline.